# Is there a way to find out the Google account currently registered to my stolen phone?

Tags: android-device-manager

Unfortunately Android Device Manager does not provide this information. It also doesn't provide an SMS feature where I can send an SMS to my stolen phone telling the current user that the phone was stolen from me.

Comment: What phone is this?

Comment: If you report the device stolen to your carrier, they will blacklist the IMEI.